# MySQL Join is the same as Cross Join?

Tags: mysql

I'm learning mysql.  Under all cases, is Join the same as Cross Join?  For example, this query

```
SELECT * FROM table t1
JOIN table t2
```

Will always be the same as

```
SELECT * FROM table t1
CROSS JOIN table t2
```

Even if I add WHERE, GROUP BY, HAVING, LIMIT, ORDER etc.... conditions afterwards, JOIN and CROSS JOIN will always yield the same results?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INNER`, `OUTER`, and `CROSS` are ignored by MySQL.  The `ON` and `WHERE` control which type of `JOIN` it is.

In your examples you have nothing tying the tables together, hence operates like a `CROSS JOIN`.

`GROUP BY`, etc have no impact.

Comment: That's not enirely correct (about the `OUTER`). The `FROM a OUTER JOIN b` will produce a syntax error.

Comment: I stand corrected.